# Is making multiple edits in chat considered spam?

Tags: support, chat

When using the chat feature, it is possible to edit a previous message for up to 120 seconds.

Is there a limit on the amount of times to edit that message?

Is it considered spam to edit the message more than a certain amount of times?

Comment: Why would it be considered spam?

Comment: @juergend - I do not think it is, but I was curious if I was incorrect.

Comment: It would be annoying in the case that the message is `@addressing` another user, because they'll get another notification each time you edit. I can't think of another situation where editing would really be discouraged.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - I agree, and I know there are other questions regarding that aspect. But I was just curious about straight edits, without the `@user` notification.

Comment: Are you asking if you'll trigger any sort of auto-ban from too many edits, or are you just asking from a social convention / politeness perspective?

Comment: @Laura - Mostly the former, I don't think it bothers or otherwise impacts other users to see multiple edits inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't spam if your edits are good/reasonable. Editing them to change there meaning is spam. But editing multiple times is fine.